# What is the chat command in linux?

Tags: command-line

I was recently trying random words in the terminal and discovered that there is a command called chat in ubuntu. I don't know if it exists in other distributions.

But I couldn't figure out its functionality

Any suggestion accepted gratefully. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you don't know what a command does, the first step is to check its manual with `man command`. In this case, you want `man chat` which will show:

> CHAT(8)                    System Manager's Manual
> CHAT(8)
>
> NAME
> chat - Automated conversational script with a modem
>
> SYNOPSIS
> chat [ options ] script
>
> DESCRIPTION
> The  chat  program  defines a conversational exchange between the computer and the modem. Its primary purpose is to establish  the  connection  between  the  Point-to-Point  Protocol Daemon (pppd) and the remote's pppd process.
>
> [ . . . ]

So `chat` is a tool that lets you communicate with a modem.

Comment: ok... I clicked the post  button for my answer, just then your answer arrived 

Answer (score 1):

The chat program defines a conversational exchange between the computer and the modem. Its primary purpose is to establish the connection between the Point-to-Point Protocol Daemon (pppd) and the remote's pppd process.

See https://linux.die.net/man/8/chat for more information